# SSRS Tablix Header Row Formatting

Tags: formatting, textbox, header, ssrs-2008

I've got several reports and they have been built with various formatting.  Nothing huge just the header row is different between them.  I'd like to pick a standard and just update the reports so they all look the same.  This can be done on a textbox by textbox basis - setting the font, font color, font size and background color.

It seems like I should be able to select more than one textbox and set the formatting on them all at once but the "textbox properties" item is disabled when I've selected more than one.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you would be better off creating a report template that you could apply to all of your reports.

Here is a link explaining how to do that: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jhermiz/archive/2007/08/14/60283.aspx

Answer (score 0):

never mind... it can easily be done by selecting the textboxes and then using the formatting toolbar at the top - just needed to ask for it to appear before my eyes.